# IntelliJ idea import android library Android-PullToRefresh

Tags: android, intellij-idea

guys! I had downloaded a android library of pull to refresh by this link: https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh.git.

After downloaded the [Android-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh), here is the directory:

[image]

According to the Quick Start Guide, I should import the library directory to my IntelliJ project. However I have problem to do this with my IntelliJ IDEA 14. I don't know how to import the library directory, here is my IntelliJ settings screen.

[image]

For the ***Libraries*** option, maybe I should import a ***.jar*** package, but I don't know how to import the library-directory.

[image]

For the ***Modules*** option, if I should create a new module, so which type I should choose?

I really have no experience with this, I need your help!

Comment: Are you talking about Swipe Refresh? I did it without importing any separate library.

Comment: File - New - Module From Existing sources - Select library folder. New Module appear in project tree. Then open modules like in picture above, select your project module, Press Add module dependency (green plus button) - select your new module. So, I suggest implement pull to refresh with standard SwipeRefreshLayout from support library

Comment: Well, no! It's not Swipe Refresh! Maybe Swipe Refresh is a good choose for me, but before I choose it I should resolve the matter. Case there're some characteristic I need in this library.

Comment: @ Georgy Gobozov Wow, so appreciated of your advice, you helped me a lot. I really suggest you systemize your comment into a good answer, it will help a lot people like me who are new to make a library-dependency of IntelliJ project. Thanks so much!